# Show header and footer only on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I want to show my header and footer only on scroll.

Based on my code, I can show header perfectly while scrolling up, but if I scroll down, header slides up and footer slides down.

It should work like this:

1. Show just the section tag
2. Scroll up => Show header
3. Scroll down => Hide header and go to content
4. Scroll down (again after showing content) => Show footer
5. Scroll up (after showing footer) => Show content

```
var lastScrollTop = 0;
$(window).on('scroll', function () {
  var st = $(this).scrollTop();
  if (st > lastScrollTop) {
    header.slideUp();
    footer.slideDown();
  }
  else {
    header.slideDown();
    footer.slideUp();
  }
});
```

```html
<header>
  ...
</header>
<section>
  ...
</seciton>
<footer>
  ...
</footer>
```

Here an image to show, how my layout is built (black areas: header and footer).

[image]

Comment: So you want there to be a discontinuous "jump" between header -> content -> footer sections? I.e., no matter how much the user scrolls down (for example), it just snaps to the next section?

Comment: @jonny yes, exactly.

Comment: as Jonny suggests, that would look unusual. Make sure your content has fixed height and is overflowing so that you can scroll it. Depending on the position of the scrollbar, slide the header or footer in with CSS transitions

Comment: @SouritraDasGupta i now it will look unusual but unfortunately my client wants it this way...